# Python/pandas merging two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I had a

```
df1 = 
  Color  count  size   price
0   Red      2   med     5
1  Blue      1   large   10
```

and another

```
df2 =

0 count
1 size
```

and wanted the two to merge so that I would have

dfmain =

```
   count  size   
0     2   med   
1     1   large
```

How would I go about implementing this? Essentially take the columns of the second dataframe and remove the rest of the columns that are not part of the second dataframe into a final dataframe. I am a pandas beginner and any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This isn't really a merge inasmuch as it is a column subset

Comment: `df1.loc[:,df2]`

Comment: df2 seems to be a series, a dataframe would have column names. if that is the case df1[df2] will return the desired result.

Comment: I see, it seems to be a series for df2, and when I implemented @Wen's method I get an error that states None of [   AMZN\n0    HD\n1   DIS\n2   NKE\n3  SBUX] are in the [columns]' (my actual project is a little more complex than the given example)

Comment: @HaleemurAli I am getting a ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ifly6 mentioned, these is more of a column subset question than a merge question.

This should work:

```
dfmain = df1.loc[:,df2.iloc[:,0]]
```

1. `df2.iloc[:,0]` selects the values from the first column of `df2`
2. `df1.loc[:,df2.iloc[:,0]]` then selects the `df1` columns (by name) as specified by the output of step 1.